# Select2 and jScrollPane

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane, jquery-select2, jquery-jscrollpane

How to combine Select2 with jScrollPane?

i came up with this:

```
$("select").select2({
    width: "300px"
});

$(document).on("select2-open", "select", function () {
    $('.select2-results').jScrollPane({
        'mouseWheelSpeed': 40
    });
});

$(document).on("select2-close", "select", function () {
    $('.select2-results').data('jsp').destroy();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b8LZJ/29/

but after using (with closing) it once, select2 stops to works (cannot select option).
is there any way to fix it? and i really need jScrollPane plugin not something else.

UPDATE 1:

i managed to make it work by reinitialising select2 on dropdown close, but i hope there is better way to do this.

```
$(document).on("select2-close", "select", function () {
    $('.select2-results').data('jsp').destroy();
    $("select").select2();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/b8LZJ/35/

Comment: you are applying jscrollpane to wrong element. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to update ;

```
 $('.select2-results').jScrollPane({
            'mouseWheelSpeed': 40
        });
```

to

```
 $(this).parent(".select2-drop").jScrollPane({
            'mouseWheelSpeed': 40
        });
```

You are applying jScrollPane to wrong element.

Here is a working demo: **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b8LZJ/36/)**

Comment: u edited the wrong fiddle and in your demo there is no jscrollpane scrollbar active, but anyway i'm applying to correct element, it works but needs corection.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I have updated answer and demo. Could you please check?

Comment: don't u see? u got the default scrollbar, not jscrollpane one, check my updated demo, it's how it should work but i'm searching for better solution.